# Remove everything before and after HTML class

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have page source in a file, however there's only a fraction of the page that I need, which is contained within this class:

```
<td class="left">
<a href="hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=xMorgan">xMorgan</a>
<br><a href="hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=unik4kosova">unik4kosova</a>
<br><a href="hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=MiscDemeanor">MiscDemeanor</a>
<br>
</td>
```

From what I understand, there's no simple way of doing this because it's not contained within an element. Is this still possible?

Comment: Without source code showing what you did, I can't say for sure, but I can say you didn't use Nokogiri to download the page, because Nokogiri doesn't do that. Probably you used OpenURI to `open` and read the file. If Nokogiri was involved it very likely didn't need to be as it's a parser, so parsing then converting to text to save would be wasted motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your expected output from the given input? Is it like the following:

```rb
"\nxMorgan\nunik4kosova\nMiscDemeanor\n"
```

If this is what you want, you can write:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('url-of-the-page-you-want-to-save'))
puts doc.css('td.left').text
```

If this is not what you want, please provide sufficient HTML sample and the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the expected output from the given input is from: <a href="hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=xMorgan">xMorgan</a> to xMorgan, i.e. stripping everything apart from the text field of the <a> tags.

Comment: Then this is what you want, you can try it out. Or maybe `doc.css('td.left a').map{|a| a.text}`

Comment: What you initially posted works absolutely brilliantly - many thanks! My only qualm is that it leaves one blank line in the file I've written to:                                                 class Strip
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("Datafiles/Input.txt"))
outFile = File.new("Output.txt", "w")
outFile.puts doc.css('td.left').text